# Text to binary converter doesn't work if I use numbers or special characters

Tags: python, text, binary, converters

There's a problem to format the string as a binary number when a space or a special character is in the input.

```
phrase = "a b"
bin_str = '0'+'0'.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in phrase)
print(bin_str)
original_string = int('0b'+bin_str,2).to_bytes((int('0b'+bin_str,2).bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode()
print(original_string)
```

I should get:
011000010010000001100010
But instead I got:
01100001010000001100010
when I tried to decode, got the error message in the line 4:

> "utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 1: invalid start byte"

If the variable phrase is "año"
I should get:
01100001110000111011000101101111
But instead I got:
0110000101111000101101111
when I tried to decode, got the error message in the line 4:

> "utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte"

I know the codec error is happening because the binary number is wrong, but I don't know why the converter is working wrong when I use an space, special character or even a number, if the ord() method uses Unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Changed this: `bin_str = '0'+'0'.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in phrase)`
to : `bin_str = '0'+bin(int.from_bytes(phrase.encode(), 'big'))[2:].zfill(8)`
and now works perfect!
PD: I still don't know the reason of why the first line wasn't working

Comment: The first version assumes that the `ord` of each character has a bit length of seven.  This is not true for `' '` (6) or `'ñ'` (8).  Also, it assumes that each character can be encoded  in UTF-8 as a single byte: this is not true for `'ñ'`.